# cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_58.lib' in VS 2013 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am attempting to compile a project in visual studio 2013 that is using boost 1.58.

I am receiving this error:

```
Error   3   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_58.lib'
```

This entry is in my VC++/General/Library Directories
$(BOOSTDIR)\lib\x64

the value of my BOOSTDIR directory is 
C:\Projects\boost_1_58_0

I have verified that the path C:\Projects\boost_1_58_0\lib\x64 has the "libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_58.lib" file.

What could I be missing?

Comment: If what you documented is accurate then you should not get this linker error.  So it isn't accurate.  Look at the actual link command to narrow it down, find it back in the tlog subdirectory.

Comment: Do you know which file to look at to see the actual link command?

Comment: Kinda hard to miss, its name starts with "link.command".

Comment: It is empty after attempting to build and receiving the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by rebuilding boost and then adding the new lib location as follows:

1. Add $(BOOSTDIR)\libs;$(BOOSTDIR)\stage\lib; to Additional Libraries
2. Add $(BOOSTDIR) to Additional Include Directories

I'm guessing there was a compiler mis-match between my project and whatever boost was built with (even though my coworker told me it was built using the same compiler). Or it could have been the path was wrong or missing.

Comment: I think you only need to include $(BOOSTDIR)\stage\lib to the Additional Libraries field.  $(BOOSTDIR)\libs doesn't appear to contain any library files.